# Скроллинг LABEL и TEXTVIEW GTK+ C

Tags: c, gtk3

есть код

```
GtkWidget *label = NULL;

label = gtk_label_new(NULL);
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), "this is label");
```

и

```
GtkWidget *textview = NULL;

textview = gtk_text_view_new();
```

*контейнеры опущены*

как сделать для `label` и `textview` полосу прокрутки, желательно очень простой пример, пожалуйста. никак не могу понять, как это делается.

Comment: textview не получает полосу, а лишь расширяет окно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GtkWidget *scrolled_window = NULL;

scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
textview = gtk_text_view_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), textview);

// gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для получения полос прокрутки надо запихнуть виджет в `GtkScrolledWindow`.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    gchar *lorem = 
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing\n"
        "elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et\n"
        "dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis\n"
        "nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\n"
        "ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in\n"
        "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore\n"
        "eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\n"
        "cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia\n"
        "deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n";

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 600, 150);

    GtkWidget *hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 4);

    GtkWidget* scrolledwindow_label = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(lorem);

    GtkWidget* scrolledwindow_text = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    GtkWidget *textview = gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(
            gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textview)), lorem, -1);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), hbox);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow_label), label);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), scrolledwindow_label, 1, 1, 4);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow_text), textview);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), scrolledwindow_text, 1, 1, 4);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: мда... меньше чем на минуту опоздал... =) удалю попозже...

Comment: Да, опоздали) Да не нужно удалять, кому-то пригодится. Но спасибо)